# Regular Expressions in Python. Checking the validity of a phone number

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a logic for checking the validity of phone number in Python. If any mobile number starting with +91 or 91 and containing 10 digits starting in between 6 -9 in entered by the user. It should be a valid phone number.
I am tried the below code but its giving me an error :
error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 9
Any help will be much appreciated.
For example :
the phone number should have any of the below formats:
+917162377291
916162377291
+918162377291
+919162377291
If user enters any of the numbers in the above format condition that the first digit post 91 or +91 should be among {6,7,8 or 9} followed by 9 digits should be a valid phone number.

```
import re 
s=input('Enter the phone number:')
m=re.fullmatch('^\(+91|91)[6-9]d{9}',s)
if m!=None:
    print('Correct Number')
else:
    print('Incorrect Number')
```

Comment: Use: `^\+?91[6-9]{8}$`, for a ten digit number starting with `91` or `+91`, followed by 8 more digits from the range 6-9.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is showing as incorrect number when i am entering the mobile number starting with country code +917xxxxxxxx. Here x represents any digit between 0 to 9.

Comment: `any digit between 0 to 9` ... but your question states any digit between _6 to 9_ ... did you make a typo?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I mean the phone number should have any of the below formats:
+917162377291
  916162377291
+918162377291
+919162377291
If user enters any of the numbers in the above format condition that the first digit post 91 or +91 should be  among {6,7,8 or 9} followed by 9 digits should be a valid phone number.

Comment: Can any one suggest me the solution for the above question ?

Answer (score 0):

So finally i was able to solve this question with the below approach of using ? as already told by @Tim Biegeleisen.

```
s=input('Enter the phone number:')
m=re.fullmatch('\+?9?1?[6-9]\d{9}',s)
if m!=None:
    print('Correct Number')
else:
    print('Incorrect Number')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by escaping the `\(` which matches a `(` char instead of being part of the group.

But match those formats, you don't need a grouping mechanism and you don't have to make the 9 and the 1 optional, only the `+`

```php
^\+?91[6-9]\d{9}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bfND1f/1)

```
s=input('Enter the phone number:')
m=re.fullmatch('\+?91[6-9]\d{9}', s)
if m!=None:
    print('Correct Number')
else:
    print('Incorrect Number')
```